# Play framework i18n and urls

Tags: playframework

I want to be able to do the following:

```
&{"some.i18n.key",@Secure.logout}
```

i get this error

```
play.exceptions.TemplateCompilationException: unable to resolve class secure.logout , unable to find class for annotation
```

if I do

```
#{set 'logoutUrl'}@{secure.logout}#{/set}
&{"some.i18n.key",logoutUrl}
```

it works just fine

Do i need to use Router.reverse here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Router.reverse`. But as you are in a template, you need to ensure that you use the fully qualified name for the Router object.

The following code should work for you.

```
&{"some.i18n.key", play.mvc.Router.reverse("Secure.logout")}
```

Comment: the question that begs asking is that since i am in a template and @Blah.doSomething() works in #{form} why not make it work with &{'mykey'}

Comment: Indeed. I would suggest raising a ticket on Lighthouse (where the bugs and roadmap for Play are kept), to add this required functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The [internationalization](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide12) section of the Play tutorial has the following example for using a link within a message by passing it as a parameter:

```
&{'logIn', actionBridge.Admin.index()}
```

Based on that, I'd expect the following to work for your case:

```
&{'some.i18n.key', actionBridge.Secure.logout()}
```

It's not well-documented.  It looks like [this ticket](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1111) is open to add it to the docs.